# How to view the the contrast statements SAS uses for type III tests?

Tags: model, sas, contrast

I am using SAS proc genmod to fit models. For example,

`proc genmod data=long_respir descending; class ID Treatment visit (ref="0"); model y = Treatment visit Treatment*Visit / dist=binomial link=logit type3 wald covb; repeated subject=ID / withinsubject=visit logor=fullclust; run;`

Where in the model statement specifying 'type3' requests SAS to output Type III tests for each of the predictor variables in the model. My question is: How can I view the contrast statements and 'L' matrix SAS uses to produce its Type III tests?

To elaborate, if I write my own contrast statement, I can include the '/ e;' at the end to view the 'L' matrix implied by my contrast. I would like to see the 'L' matrix implied by the contrasts SAS uses to produce the Type III tests. I cannot find how I can get SAS to give me that.

I have read the SAS proc genmod documentation for both the model statement and contrast statement and I do not see an option to get what I desire. So, either there is not an option to get this or I am overlooking something.

Comment: Credit to StatDave in SAS communities for providing an acceptable [answer](https://communities.sas.com/t5/Statistical-Procedures/How-do-I-view-the-contrasts-SAS-uses-for-Type-III-tests/m-p/869417/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufExHRFRINDY2MjMwSUtCfDg2OTQxN3xTVUJTQ1JJUFRJT05TfGhL#M43020). The note [here](https://support.sas.com/kb/22/576.html) details how one can view the general form of the Type III tests by using PROC GLM.